# Can't decrypt message encrypted in Java

Tags: java, c++, openssl, rsa

I want to share data from a server (c++) and client (Java). For security, we use a RSA key (1024 bits, 65537 exponent)

I generate my keypair like this  (C++/OpenSSL):

```c
RSA *keyPair = RSA_generate_key(RSA_BITS, RSA_EXPONENT, NULL, NULL);

BIO* privateKey = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO* publicKey = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(privateKey, keyPair, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(publicKey, keyPair);
```

My server sends the public key to my client:

Client crypt data like this (Java):

```java
Cipher m_cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
m_cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

byte[] result = m_cipher.doFinal(dataNeedToCrypt);
```

Now I receive my message, I try to decrypt it like this (C++/OpenSSL) :

```c++
BIO* privateKey = StringtoBio(m_privateKey);
RSA* rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(privateKey, NULL, NULL, NULL);

char dataDecryptedBuffer[RSA_size(rsa)];

int result = RSA_private_decrypt(RSA_size(rsa), (uchar*)data.data(), (uchar*)&dataDecryptedBuffer, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);

if(result == -1)
    CONSOLE_ERROR << "Can't decrypt error code : " << std::hex << ERR_get_error();

QByteArray dataDecrypted(dataDecryptedBuffer);

BIO_free_all(privateKey);
RSA_free(rsa);

return dataDecrypted;
```

I get an error 0x407109F, and it appears the padding is wrong:

```
$ openssl errstr 0x407109F
error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error
```

In java Cipher "RSA" is "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", so the padding should be good.

But I can't decrypt my message!

What is wrong?

Comment: Thank you @jww , i have edited my post following your advice.

Comment: Once you get decryption to succeed, you will need `result` because it holds the size of the decrypted data. It will be used like `QByteArray dataDecrypted(dataDecryptedBuffer /*data*/, result /*length*/);` (or whatever Qt uses to specify the length of a `QByteArray`.

Comment: Have you told your C code that you're using ECB?

Comment: Related, you got an error message of `error:0407109F:rsa routines:func<113>:reason<159>` because you are using an older version of the library. If you update the library (or use an updated version of the `openssl` command), then you will get a [more] useful `errstr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the way you are doing decryption:

```
int result = RSA_public_decrypt(RSA_size(rsa), (uchar*)data.data(), (uchar*)&dataDecryptedBuffer, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);    
if(result == -1)
    CONSOLE_ERROR << "Can't decrypt error code : " << std::hex << ERR_get_error();

QByteArray dataDecrypted(dataDecryptedBuffer);
```

I'm guessing you are assuming there are no `NULL` or `\0` in the cipher text. That's not the case - there can be NULLs in the cipher text.

Java should be sending all the cipher text since the `byte[]` has an explicit size. But you are probably reading it wrong when you receive it over the wire, or handling it wrong once received.

I see you are using `data.data()`, which I believe means you have a `std::string`. Be sure you are constructing the string with an explicit length, and not assuming the there's a `NULL` terminator. Or better, perform these asserts so the code debugs itself (you have better things to do with your time):

```
ASSERT(data.size() == RSA_size(rsa));
if(data.size() != RSA_size(rsa))
    CONSOLE_ERROR << "Invalid cipher text length" << endl;

int result = RSA_private_decrypt(RSA_size(rsa), (uchar*)data.data(), (uchar*)&dataDecryptedBuffer, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);

ASSERT(result != -1);
if(result == -1)
    CONSOLE_ERROR << "Can't decrypt error code : " << std::hex << ERR_get_error();

QByteArray dataDecrypted(dataDecryptedBuffer, result);
```

---

Related, the OpenSSL project recommends using high level `EVP_*` interfaces, and not the low level functions. For that, see [EVP](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: thank you @jww you have right, my receive data is wrong.
Missing some operation !